# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Module.action2' when changing property in method

Tags: javascript, c#, closures

I've read *Scope Closure* section in *Scope & Closure* chapter of the book **You don't know js**. The section url: [You don't know js](https://maximdenisov.gitbooks.io/you-don-t-know-js/content/scope_&_closures/scope_closure.html)

And I wonder if it is possible to implement the module pattern which metioned in the section in C#?

I've tried the following code but get the error in title, am I doing something wrong? Or there're any other ways to achieve this?

**The C# code**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Module module = new Module();
        Module.PublicAPIClass publicAPIClass = module.GetAPI();

        publicAPIClass.PublicAPI.Invoke();
        publicAPIClass.ChangeAPI();
        publicAPIClass.PublicAPI.Invoke();
    }
}

public class Module
{
    protected Action action1 = () => { Console.WriteLine("API1"); };

    protected Action action2 = () => { Console.WriteLine("API2"); };

    public class PublicAPIClass
    {
        public Action PublicAPI { get; set; }

        public void ChangeAPI()
        {
            PublicAPI = action2; //error here
        }
    }

    public PublicAPIClass GetAPI()
    {
        PublicAPIClass publicAPIClass = new PublicAPIClass();
        publicAPIClass.PublicAPI = action1;

        return publicAPIClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to apply JS idioms to C#? What problem are you trying to solve with the 'module pattern'? C# has other ways to 'solve' the same problem (e.g. namespaces).

Comment: It's just a try when reading the book. Maybe the PublicAPIClass is unnecessary, but I want to know why I got this error. @mjwills

Comment: Thanks. @mjwills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `PublicAPIClass` you are trying to access a non-static field of `Module` - which is not allowed. *You can't read non-static fields of other classes **without an instance of that class**.*

To fix this you need to either change `action2` to be `static`:

```
static Action action2 = () => { Console.WriteLine("API2"); };
```

Or change the way you are reading from `action2`:

```
PublicAPI = new Module().action2; //no longer an error here
```